# How far are enemies knocked back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Enchanted swords can receive two levels of **Knockback** while bows can receive two levels of **Punch**.  How far do these enchantments knock the enemy back and how does it compare to the knockback from normally hitting and/or sprinting?

Comment: As of note, knockback can go much higher than 2 (if you or the server-admin are willing to hex-edit your player file) but the game will only ever give you 2 maximum. (Per my friend: Looting 200 will crash the server.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**After a significant amount of testing,** of which GLaDOS would be proud, we managed to come up with a fairly simple table of data from which to formulate an answer.

[image: The pull of the bow makes no difference]
<sup>Variation of about .5 blocks</sup>

To reach these results, I first enchanted my weapons until I had **Knockback I** and **Knockback II** (note: the minimum modified levels for these enchants are 5 and 25, respectively).

[image]

I then had my associate spawn Zombies in the **Knockback Testing Super System™** so that I could attack the Zombies from a safe, secure location.

[image]

We first tested a *Normal Sword* (no enchantment) from a standing position, and then again while sprinting. We then repeated the process with enchanted swords. Once we reached a definitive conclusion, we moved on to testing with *Bows* and their related enchantments (in this case **Punch**). **The results of our *SCIENCE* can be found at the top of this answer.**

I hope this helped!

[image]

Comment: I certainly hope that there was cake after this rigorous testing.

Comment: Why do you have a pokeball?

Comment: @BenBrocka He has the Pokeball because... A wild nihilistronin appears!

Comment: during the testing did you guys check how long the mob would be in the air?