# How much knockback does a normal punch do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How far are enemies knocked back?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57333/how-far-are-enemies-knocked-back)

I have a feeling I was encountering someone with a hacked client, but just to make sure, about how much knockback does a normal punch do in Minecraft? Is it normal to be knocked back 4-5 blocks, or was the other player probably cheating?

Comment: 4-5 blocks seems like a lot to me...

Answer (score 5):

Regular attacks only inflict slight knockback.

It's very likely that he was sprinting for a split second before hitting you.

If you punch someone while sprinting it inflicts a lot more knockback. 4-5 blocks isn't an unreasonable distance to punch someone while sprinting.